# Convert INT to DATE in WHERE clause - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Working with sysjobs and sysjobhistory on SQL Server and I have been googling around but I can't seem to find a direct answer to this question. I think it is because I'm trying to do this in a WHERE clause.

So basically trying to select a job that has failed on the same day that it ran (basically today's date), since the current code is selecting all of the existing jobs that failed.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sj.name,
    COUNT(sjh.instance_id) AS errors
FROM 
    msdb..sysjobhistory sjh 
JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
WHERE 
    name IN ('SQLAgentJob1', 'SQLAgentJob2')
    AND sjh.run_status = 1
    AND (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(INT, sjh.run_date), 112)) = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 112))
GROUP BY 
    sj.name
```

I keep getting an error stating:

> Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
>   Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the point of those being subqueries?

Comment: I am assuming it doesn't have to be in a subquery?

Comment: It isn't the root of the issue but they don't need to be subqueries.

Comment: So what is the root cause of the issue then? And how would I go about with the conversion? Like where would I place it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do all those conversions, just convert your parameter (ie the current date) to the unseparated date format with 112:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sj.name, COUNT(sjh.instance_id) AS errors
FROM msdb..sysjobhistory sjh 
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
WHERE name IN ('SQLAgentJob1','SQLAgentJob2')
    AND sjh.run_status = 1
    AND sjh.run_date= CONVERT(nvarchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
GROUP BY sj.name
```

There is no integer to date conversion because there is no integer representation for dates.

The `run_date` column stores the `YYYYMMDD` format as an integer, perhaps to reduce space consumption (4 bytes instead of 8), perhaps for some other reason.

To compare against it, just create the equivalent string with `CONVERT(nvarchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)`. The conversion from string to integer is implicit

Comment: Plus1 Better only 1 conversion

Comment: The multiple conversions are what caused this query to fail

Comment: So, is there a difference between your answer and jhilden's answer? Both came back with the same results. I am assuming both has the same logic too.

Comment: @AznDevil92 no, it isn't the same logic at all. There is no reason to convert `run_date` just as there is no reason to cast `GETDATE()` to a date. Just convert the date to the correct string format. If `run_date` was indexed, the double conversion would prevent the optimizer from using the index

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sj.name,
    COUNT(sjh.instance_id) AS errors
FROM msdb..sysjobhistory sjh 
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
WHERE name IN ('SQLAgentJob1',
               'SQLAgentJob2')
            AND sjh.run_status = 1
            AND CAST(CONVERT(datetime, CAST(SJH.[run_date] AS CHAR(8))) as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
            GROUP BY sj.name
```

## Explanation

- First convert from int to datetime
- Cast down from datetime to date (drop the time)
- Compare against today's date (with the time dropped)

Comment: There is no reason to perform all these conversions

Comment: I agree, the other answer is a better one.